# How do websites check the login credentials without reloading the page?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, authentication, optimization

Some websites, such as [Yahoo](https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?.intl=ca&.src=ym) and [Google](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&hl=en), use Ajax to check if the username/password is wrong. Obviously there must be server side authentication because anyone can change the local JavaScript and trick it into thinking username/password is correct. I'm wondering how this is done efficiently since wouldn't the server be checking the same username/password twice? Consider the following scenario where a user logs into a web site:

1. a user comes to the log in page
2. user enters username/password and clicks submit
3. through Ajax the server communicates with the client if the username/password entered are correct
4. Server replies saying whether the username/password is correct - in this example it is
5. The `<form>` is submitted and an intermittent page takes the inputted values through `POST` and processes them again on the server side to verify if the username/password is correct and if it is sets a variable in the session

In step 5 the server checks for the second time if the same username/password is correct as in step 3. Is there a way to cache the result from step 3 or make the process more efficient? Also the server has already been sent the username/password in step 3. but I'm not sure if that could accelerate the process.

I'm using a MySQL database to store user names and passwords.

Comment: The server can create that session  or cookie at 4. No need to check for the user/pw again

Comment: The server will set session var or cookie

Comment: just want to point out: step 3, javascript itself cant query a database, ajax would be the correct term there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At step 3 your `onsubmit` handler will send your AJAX request to the server to validate credentials ***and*** prevent the normal form submission (by calling `.preventDefault()` in the handler or returning false from the handler), so step 5 will never happen.
If javascript is disabled then you won't have an onsubmit handler and the normal form submission will take place instead.

In your step 4, if you receive a "correct" response then your AJAX handler can redirect to a new page; if it's an "incorrect" response you'd stay on the login page, clear the form, and put up your error message.

Comment: So basically if the response from the server if the password/username are correct then `onsubmit` handler will create a session and return true, otherwise false will be returned (thus preventing the page from being redirected) and a message to the user saying "wrong username/password" will be displayed?

Comment: @Celeritas - Basically Yes, though the onsubmit handler is javascript on the client, and it's the server that should be creating the session. One way could be for the server to create the session and pass the session ID back to the client when the username/password is correct. The server could reply with a JSONP message that includes the javascript method to create the session cookie.

Answer (score 1):

At point 3, the JS should be submitting your form to server side processing and waiting for a response. If JS is disabled then the form would just submit normally.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment says, not sure i completely agree with your process there, this is how i would picture it

1. a user comes to the log in page
2. user enters username/password and clicks submit
3. Jquery triggers the onclick action, grabbing the user input, sends an ajax request to php, php sanitizes and queries to see if the credentials are found.
4. If they are php sets session and cookie and returns the ajax result.
5. If the credentials are not correct, the php handles that issue as well.

**OR** *if you didnt want to use ajax*

1. a user comes to the log in page
2. user enters username/password and clicks submit
3. the form routes to a php page the querys the database for user credentials, if they are correct, set session and cookie and redirect to correctLogin.php
4. if not redirect to incorrectLogin.php

Comment: Javascript and jquery isn't synonym.

Comment: I never said they were, but frankly i find the click event easier to use with jquery

Comment: But @Nick you should use the submit event on the form, not the click event on the submit button. (which doesn't change your point about jquery)

Comment: @StephenP if yorue running an ajax query it makes no sense to use the form submit function, if you base the event fired off of jquery, you can just send the result and return with ajax via the jquery, jquery also handles ajax a lot better than javascript does in my opinion. in the end you can use javascript or jquery. i just listed it due to the fact that it is my preference.

Comment: @Nick I agree and use jQuery myself as it does event handling and ajax so much cleaner than plain javascript. My point is that a form can be submitted without the submit button ever being clicked; it makes perfect sense to use the submit event and it's better to bind to submit than to click. I do this everywhere - the regular form submission is prevented, instead the submit event handler sends off the ajax query. But a normal submit is done if someone has javascript turned off / blocked. This works even if the submit button is never clicked, and also if the form is submitted programatically.

Comment: Wow i looked right over that, you are in fact correct, I apologize for disagreeing with you, i think i misunderstood your initial point :p